# Let $\frac{{{x^5}}}{{1 - {x^5} + {x^{10}}}} = k$. What is $\frac{{{x^{15}}}}{{1 - {x^{15}} + {x^{30}}}}$?

Tags: calculus

Let $\frac{{{x^5}}}{{1 - {x^5} + {x^{10}}}} = k$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}$.

What is $\frac{{{x^{15}}}}{{1 - {x^{15}} + {x^{30}}}}$?

Comment: Observe first that you may as well set $z = x^5$, since only 5-th powers of $x$ appear in both formulae. Now pick various values of $z$ and compute both $z/(1-z+z^2)$ and $z^3/(1-z^3+z^6)$. Can you see any pattern?

Comment: The same hints and tips to [that other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022239/let-fracx21-x4-frac13-what-is-fracx41-x) apply in this case as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$
1-a+a^2=\frac{1+a^3}{1+a}
$$

Or use that with $a=x^5$
$$
a+\frac1a=1+\frac1k\implies a^3+3a+3\frac1a+\frac1{a^3}=\left(1+\frac1k\right)^3
$$

Comment: Please more guide.

Comment: You are looking for the inverse of $a^3+\frac1{a^3}$ which is easy to extract from the second hint.

Answer (score 5):

Note that
$$
k=\frac{x^5}{1-x^5+x^{10}}=\frac{1}{x^{-5}-1+x^{5}}\implies x^{-5}-1+x^{-5}=k^{-1}.
$$

It follows that
\begin{aligned}
k^{-2}&=1+(x^{-10}+x^{10})-2(x^{-5}-1+x^5)\implies(x^{-10}+x^{10})=k^{-2}-1+2k^{-1},\\
k^{-3}&=(x^{-5}-1+x^{-5})^3=(x^{-15}-1+x^{15})+6(x^{-5}-1+x^5)-3(x^{-10}+x^{10}).
\end{aligned}
We conclude
$$
x^{-15}-1+x^{-15}=k^{-3}-6k^{-1}+3(k^{-2}-1+2k^{-1})=k^{-3}+3k^{-2}-3
$$
and the desired answer the reciprocal of the rightmost expression above:
$$
\frac{k^3}{1+3k-3k^3}.
$$

Comment: It should be $\frac{k^3}{1+3k-3k^3}$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks a lot. I edited.